# Why can I not install more than three apps?

Tags: ios, xcode8

I have just started learning how to make iOS apps, and am using the free personal developer account.

I have made four apps so far, but do not seem to be able to install more than three apps. Even if I have three apps installed, and go to update one of the installed apps I receive the following error message in Xcode:

> #### App installation failed
>
> The maximum number of apps for free development profiles has been reached.

From what I have read, each app should be signed for a week, but I've only been coding from a few days.

How can I install more apps, or do I have to delete my existing apps from my device?

Comment: Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61953293

Answer (score 27):

Just **delete the apps that you have installed using the same profile** from your device. just clean the project by using the command **SHIFT+Command+K** ,Try to run the project again.In my case it worked .No need to pay any fee.I hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 25):

Go to `Window` -> `Devices and Simulators`. Then **delete** any apps from the **INSTALLED APPS** section. Just clean and run the project. It worked for me.
[image: Installed apps screenshots]

Answer (score 10):

For me by removing unnecessary provisioning profiles from the device.

1. In the Xcode go to Window → Devices and Simulators.
2. Right click the device you are unable to install app.
3. Delete some provisioning profiles.

Clean App and then run will work.

Comment: Deleting provisioning profiles manually fixed this problem for me, big thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The actual limitation for the number of applications on a free developer account (at the time of writing) seems to be like this:

- Three usable apps (I mean: 3 apps with an active provisioning profile)

But, probably due to an error the way Apple counts, you can't compile and install directly the third app. You have to remove it from the device before installing.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there was not a satisfactory answer yet...

It is a big sudden problem that came with OSX10. There are several errors I and others report:

> on new project:
>
> > 1/ The maximum number of apps for free development profiles has been reached.
>
> on the project working on macOS before 10 (8 or 9) .
>
> > 1/ mycode0001 requires a provisioning profile. Select a provisioning profile for the "Debug" build configuration in the project editor.
> >
> > 2/ Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'

It is critical for quite a few developers to know how to address this!

Comment: any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved this issue: 
I deleted all my test apps in the emulator and on the iPhone. Additionaly, I removed them in iTunes. Afterwards that message disappeared and I was able to build my app.

Answer (score 1):

I just delete one app installed using the same profile, then it works. Besides I change another Apple Develper ID, then it works.

Answer (score 0):

I faced issue when I have many out of date apps in test device, like that:

[image]

So I tried:

**Step 1**: Connect to test device

**Step 2**: **Window** -> **Devices and Simulators** -> Select test device

**Step 3**: Click **Open Console**

**Step 4**: Build App in test device

**Step 5**: Paste `MIFreeProfileValidatedAppTracker` to Search input

**Step 6**: Update or delete these apps with `bundle id` in list:

```
[MIFreeProfileValidatedAppTracker _onQueue_addReferenceForApplicationIdentifier:bundle:error:]: 182: This device has reached the maximum number of installed apps using a free developer profile: {(
    "bundle id 1",
    "bundle id 2",
    "bundle id 3",
    "bundle id 4"
)}
```