# Xcode: Could not locate installed application. Install claimed to have succeeded, but application could not be found on device

Tags: ios, xcode

I manually deleted my app from the iPhone and now I get this error message when trying to run it again from Xcode.

I cleaned the build folder, restarted the device, Xcode and the Mac, nothing helps.

I also tried everything that's mentioned here: [Install claimed to have succeeded, but application could not be found on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241579/install-claimed-to-have-succeeded-but-application-could-not-be-found-on-device)

How do I force a re-installation?

Answer (score 13):

As always, when the question is posted on SO, one finds a solution ;)

I edited the Scheme, setting the build configuration from debug to release and that installed the app again. Changed it back to debug and now it's running again as expected.

Comment: This finally did it for me after trying so many of the other SO solutions.  In my case, what fixed it was going from Release back to Debug.  I think what triggered it was I deleted the app on the phone while it was in the middle of being installed from Xcode.

Answer (score 13):

I ran into the same issue while testing a app on iOS 13 via XCode 11.0. Building via the legacy system solved it (File > Workspace Settings... > Build System > Legacy Build System).

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks, seems when Xcode 11 silently updated, the legacy build system got reset to new build system. Affects all ionic projects.

Comment: Installing it once via the **Legacy Build System** to get rid of this error, and then switching back to the **New build system** works as well :)

Comment: To understand *why* you can't build with **Release** configuration into your iPhone from Xcode. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62432103/5175709)

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue after one of Carthage/XCode updates. It means iOS was not able to install app on the phone. XCode apparently is not able to provide this information directly. The first thing to do is open your phone console - go to `Window/Devices and Simulators` then select your device and click `Open Console`. In the console you can search for your app name what should provide you more detailed fail info. In my case it was sth like this:

```
Applications did fail to install: (
    "<LSApplicationProxy: 0x118913b60> com.mydomain.myapp (null) <com.mydomain.myapp <INVALID >:0>"
) (appInfos: (null))
```

There was another console log few rows before flagging the problem:

```
0x16f4df000 -[MIExecutableBundle codeSigningInfoByValidatingResources:performingOnlineAuthorization:ignoringCachedSigningInfo:checkingTrustCacheIfApplicable:error:]: 789: Code signing identifier (org.alamofire.Alamofire.iphonesimulator) does not match bundle identifier (org.alamofire.Alamofire.iphoneos) for /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.E83T1l/extracted/myapp.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework
```

There was an issue with one of the frameworks `Alamofire` I'm using in the project. I changed bundle identifier of the project and build framework again what solved the problem.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the problem was an embedded framework that was not being signed.  In the General tab of the project settings, setting the embed setting to 'Embed & Sign' did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was a problem with new Development certificate. It's created automatically after Xcode updated to 11 and may not be included in current provisioning profile.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing similar issue in Xcode 11.1. I have fix this issue. Not sure about this solution that it will to work for all or not.

My device iOS version was older then the iOS Xcode target build version.

Steps:

1. I have put Xcode target Device to iPhone device OS version.
2. Delete derived data
3. Start xcode and open project
4. Clean the project and gererate build and install in device

Note: Please check your developer account, certificate validation and already registered device warning.

Hope this solution will help some peoples. Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks, this solution solved the problem for me on Xcode 11.1

Answer (score 2):

After trying everything here, for me the solution was to change my distribution profile to use the new Apple distribution certificate that covers all apple platforms. This should be compliant with xcode 11 (if you're not experiencing one of the other million problems since the "upgrade").

The cert change is mentioned here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_release_notes

Cert creation instructions here:
https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/devbfa00fef7

Once done, make sure the correct profile is selected in Signing & Capabilities, and 'Apple Distribution' is selected under Build Setting -> Signing for the appropriate build configurations

Answer (score 2):

A solution that solved this issue for me was to check the signing team for my tests  target. Selecting the same development team then meant that my app was able to be built and run on device.

Build system: New Build System

Xcode: Version 11.1

Answer (score 1):

On your iPhone go to Settings/General/Profiles & Devices/Apple Development: "YOUR APPLE ID" and delete all apps from there. It fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much! I have been stuck for days and this worked for me. However, on my device (iOS 12.4) the apps are found in 'Settings/General/Device Management/*'. I deleted the apps installed under an older certificate from XCode 10 and from under the new certificate formatted as stated above ('Apple Development: apple_id'). Now running apps is working fine!

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall all the other apps that are under the same "Organization" or "Bundle Identifier" with your current app and try again.

It works for me. Hope it does for you too.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me when trying to launch a watchOS app on a real device.

The only solution that worked was:

- Delete iOS app from device
- Delete watchOS app from device
- Close and reopen Xcode
- Clean build folder

Answer (score 0):

As for me, 
I added a custom key-value to `Info.plist` of main watchOS application file. That was wrong.
After removing it, all works correctly.
It seems this is not allowed but where is no other information about it.

Comment: this was actualy also my problem. i had the google maps API key input wrong

Answer (score 0):

I did a Product -> Clean then Build, and it was able to run.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings on your phone and wipe out all certificates and apps and then install your app again. That helped me

Answer (score 0):

Problem occured on XCode 11

TL;DR:

Try changing `Embed` option in General=>Section Frameworks, Libraries.. to `Do Not Embed` (although it sounds strange)

In my General=>Section Frameworks, Libraries.. list are `Security.framework` and the CocoaPods `Pods_projectname.framework` amongst others. Default setting of these two was `Do Not Embed`. Sounded strange to me, so I changed it without need alternating to `Embed & Sign` or `Embed Without Signing`. With both options the error occured!

Answer (score 0):

On your iPhone go to Settings/General/Profiles & Devices/Apple Deelopment: "YOUR APPLE ID" and delete all apps from there. It fixed the problem for me.

This was the solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please double check the bundle ID of the installed application to see if it is re-applied, this will also cause this problem .I uninstall the app and solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i have PROD certificate and trying to install the app in the device, later i changed to development certificate it got installed.

Answer (score 0):

As Marcin's answer suggested, I visited the phone console and in my case, it is this error message:

```
-[MIFreeProfileValidatedAppTracker _onQueue_addReferenceForApplicationIdentifier:bundle:error:]: 182: This device has reached the maximum number of installed apps using a free developer profile: {(
```

So if you are signing your app with a Personal Team certificate, make sure that you don't have more than 3 apps.

Read more here: [Why can I not install more than three apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39581127/why-can-i-not-install-more-than-three-apps/43390934)

Answer (score -1):

If you have other under-development apps installed, try uninstalling those you are not using, and run Xcode to install your app again. It works for me.