# Xcode could not locate the installed application

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode11, apple-developer

In XCode 11 when I trying to run the app xcode showing installation successful but a alert appears with message "Could not locate installed application Install claimed to have succeeded, but application could not be found on device. bundleId = com.xxx.xxx "

I tried all solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56614661/xcode-could-not-locate-installed-application-install-claimed-to-have-succeeded?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241579/install-claimed-to-have-succeeded-but-application-could-not-be-found-on-device&ved=2ahUKEwiTjbTHnPHkAhWBb30KHWrVDpUQjjgwAHoECAYQAg&usg=AOvVaw2GyZTNyYeBfR2IWGPXnPry&cshid=1569595246995)

But these solutions didn't work for me.
Please help me regarding this.

Comment: Could you please provide more info? For example, what kind of an app (iOS? macOS?) What is your destination? (Mac? iPhone? iPad? Simulator?) what is the target OS version? Anything else specific to the project worth knowing? Does it happen on a freshly created new project?

Comment: I have faced this issue in my iOS app in iphone 6 to iPhone XS Max (all device in this range) and in ipad pro. The code was working fine with xcode 10.3 but when I updated my xcode to 11 then this problem occurs and now I facing this issue in both xcode in 11 and in 10.3. and yes I have paid developer account.

Comment: Please, try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58117854/3241041

Comment: @alxlives thanks but it's not working for me

Comment: Hi! I know it might sound silly, but have you tried to restart the devices?

Comment: @summerfinn3 thanks, but I already tried these all solutions. Even I did reset one of device.

Comment: I solved this by changing my bundle identifier _and_ changing the bundle identifier of all embedded binaries to match.

Comment: @matt the only solution that I have found is only by changing the bundle identifier. But I haven't found what is wrong with the previous identifier even when I used that in xcode 10 and it was working fine.

Comment: - In my case, I have selected the AppStore provision profile. I changed to development and it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This popped up for me.  I was able too solve the problem by selecting "Automatically manage signing" on the *Signing and Capabilities* tab of the Project's application target configuration panels.

[image: Project Property Pane Screenshot]

Interestingly, I was able to then change it back and it installed, ran and debugged properly.  Go figure

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I've found is by simply changing the bundle identifier.  But I could not find what is wrong with the previous identifier while I used it in xcode 10 as well and it was working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Run you code in debug mode instead release mode. you can change to debug mode from edit scheme.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that the debugger cannot attach to your process after it is launched, try to enable the verbose of the debugger like explained [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33524051/how-to-debug-ios-share-extension) and see if it show some error.

L-

Answer (score 0):

i my case, i go to Product -> Schema -> Edit Schema

go to Build Tab on the left, uncheck everything on {projectName}Tests

Close

then run on device Again.

the other solution that work with me is 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58689652/4289609

Answer (score 0):

In my case below steps helped

1. Make sure that you are not trimming any linked framework using `lipo command`