# The maximum number of apps for free development profiles has been reached

Tags: swift, xcode

I can't get any apps to run on my iPhone. I have uninstalled the apps on the device and from the window -> Devices section. Does anyone know how else to fix this?

Details

```
enter code hereUnable to install "App Name"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620383
--
The maximum number of apps for free development profiles has been reached.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620383
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 487925;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8008021)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001253b381a DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 233
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001253f4f70 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 155
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010c117155 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 73
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001253f4ca8 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1654
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000012526be91 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.352 + 4165
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010c24a7f4 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010c24c436 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 1194
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6eea06c4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6eea1658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6eea6c44 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 597
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6eea75d6 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 363
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6eeb0c09 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 596
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6f0fba3d _pthread_wqthread + 290
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6f0fab77 start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 10.15.5 (Build 19F96)
Xcode 11.5 (16139)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can I not install more than three apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39581127/why-can-i-not-install-more-than-three-apps)

Comment: @koen Unfortunately, no. I removed all of the installed apps and I've cleaned the build folder and I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61953293/the-maximum-number-of-apps-for-free-development-profiles-has-been-reached-xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still fairly new to Xcode (less than a month and Swift is my first language), but I ran into the same problem as you and I understand how frustrating it is. After doing some digging and tinkering around, I found that the new  iOS 13.5 and Xcode 11.5 Update kind of counted other apps as free developer apps.

I ran the app multiple times in an attempt to install and searched for the error on the console. You can click Window>Devices and Simulators>Open Console. Click on your phone and search `[MIFreeProfileValidatedAppTracker]`

Once you find it, it should list down apps that are installed. I deleted those apps one by one until it freed up some space to install the current app that I am building.

The console should open up something similar to this. I found that you can leave up to 4 installed applications. Good luck!

```
0x16d05f000 -[MIFreeProfileValidatedAppTracker _onQueue_addReferenceForApplicationIdentifier:bundle:error:]: 182: This device has reached the maximum number of installed apps using a free developer profile: {(
    "com.apple.Fitness",
    "Random",
    "com.apple.DocumentsApp",
    "Random"
)}
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver! I'm new to swift as well and this completely fixed my problem! Thank you so much for your help! :)