# Xcode error maximum app limit reach when trying to run app on my iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode11

This is one question I am searching for all over the internet, got a lot of results but not for my situation.

As I don't have any apps installed on my device I didn't know how to solve this problem.

What should happen: 
 - Xcode should install the app for testing camera features I am implementing

What actually happen: 
 - Xcode fail to install the app saying there is more than three apps installed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can I not install more than three apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39581127/why-can-i-not-install-more-than-three-apps)

Comment: I tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39581127/why-can-i-not-install-more-than-three-apps but none of the solutions worked. Then I tried Bruno's answer and gave my phone a good clean up and it worked. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

As I was about to ask this question, I found somewhere that if I have some apps with the cloud symbol on them like they are in "suspense animation", as I like to call it, you need to delete all apps with this cloud symbol *(because you don't use this apps so often they just get partially deleted from your device, meaning you have short storage)*

So I am posting this because maybe is the same scenario for a lot of fellows here and could be something to try!

I hope this may help some folks!

Cheers mates!

Comment: I tried every solutions in this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39581127/why-can-i-not-install-more-than-three-apps but none of them worked for me. Then I tried Bruno's answer and gave my phone a good clean up and it worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hey Zephyr, I faced this problem for a long time without answers, then I tried this... was my last hope LOL. I am glad that helped you man!